# How do I remove spaces in all attribute values using xslt?

Tags: xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0, removing-whitespace

I want to remove spaces from all attributes in my xmls using xslt. I used `strip-space`, but that removes the spaces from nodes.
My input xml is:

```
<OrderList>
<Order OrderDate="26-July" OrderNo="ORDER 12345"
 CustomertName="JOHN DOE" OrderKey="ORDKEY12345">
<ShipAddress AddressLine="ABC Colony" FirstName="John" LastName="Doe "/>
</Order>
</OrderList>
```

and the xsl I used to get rid of the spaces in the attributes like `CustomertName="JOHN DOE"` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
<OrderList>
    <xsl:for-each select="OrderList/Order">
        <xsl:element name="Order">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@OrderDate"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@OrderNo"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@CustomertName"/>

            <!-- ShipAddress begins -->
            <xsl:element name="ShipAddress">                                           
                <xsl:copy-of select="ShipAddress/@AddressLine"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ShipAddress/@FirstName"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ShipAddress/@LastName"/>                       
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>             
</OrderList>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this leaves the input xml as it was. I want to remove the spaces from the attribute values at all levels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the translate function, like so, although it would make sense to refactor this with a call template:

```
<xsl:attribute name="OrderDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@OrderDate, ' ','')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="OrderNo">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@CustomertName, ' ','')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="CustomertName">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@CustomertName, ' ','')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Hey thanks...but i was looking for something more generic...:)

Comment: @SMA_JAVA to strip just leading and trailing space, use *normalize-space(@CustomertName)*

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to removes spaces from the values of attributes, you could just create a template to match any attribute, and then use the translate function.

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')" />
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

And if you want to filter out some attributes, you can create templates to match, and then ignore them. (XSLT will match the more specific template first)

```
<xsl:template match="Order/@OrderKey" />
```

You can also simplify you code somewhat by making use of the identity transform to cope existing nodes. Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')" />
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Order/@OrderKey" />

   <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is ouptut

```
<OrderList>
  <Order OrderDate="26-July" OrderNo="ORDER12345" CustomertName="JOHNDOE">
    <ShipAddress AddressLine="ABCColony" FirstName="John" LastName="Doe"></ShipAddress>
  </Order>
</OrderList>
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will work with any XML document.

If you wanted to do this only for specific elements, try this XSLT instead which explicitly matches the attributes you want (and discards all others)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Order/@OrderDate|Order/@OrderNo|Order/@CustomertName|ShipAddress/@AddressLine|ShipAddress/@FirstName|ShipAddress/@LastName">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted to remove only leading and trailing spaces, then 'normalize-space' is your friend.

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
```

Do note this will remove excess spaces within the attribute though (that is to say double-spaces become single spaces between words).

Comment: Thanks a ton Tim,
Also if I want to remove only leading and trainling whitespaces...what can i use then? Any help with this?

Comment: I've edited my answer. `normalize-space` is the function you probably need!

Comment: Hey but one thing...I am also filtering out some attributes, if you see my xsl, OrderList\Order\@OrderKey was not there. But if i use your xsl, it will not filter out OrderKey, it will just copy all the attributes minus the leading and trailing spaces.
Some more help with this please...

Comment: I've expanded the answer to show how you can exclude specific attributes

Comment: okk...so say i already have the xsl created which looks like the first xsl and i dont want to change it much apart from adding that bit to remove the leading and trailing whitespaces...for your code we are actually adding the attributes that require a removal, but my xsl only has the attributes which needs to be passed.
When i use the whitespace removal bit along with my xsl, it gives the xml without whitespaces, but also with that appends the original input xml...and so it looks like...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<OrderList>
<Order OrderDate="26-July" OrderNo="ORDER12345" CustomertName="JOHNDOE" OrderHeaderKey="ORDKEY12345">
<ShipAddress AddressLine="ABCColony" FirstName="John" LastName="Doe"></ShipAddress>
</Order>
</OrderList>
<OrderList>
<Order OrderDate="26-July" OrderNo="ORDER 12345" CustomertName="JOHN DOE">
<ShipAddress AddressLine="ABC Colony" FirstName="John" LastName="Doe " />
</Order>
</OrderList>

Comment: I've added another XSLT sample to show how you would do it if you only wanted specific attributes.